# How long can you store beer?

Tags: storage

Assuming a relatively cool and stable environment, how long can you store beer in:

- Bottles
- Wooden barrels
- Metallic barrels
- Cans (Yes, I really asked that.)

without it loosing its carbonation and taste or going off?
Are there general rules that apply to any sort of beer or is this highly specific?

(Please note that this question is not about intentionally aging the beer, just storing it.)

Comment: This is *really* broad. Perhaps narrowing it down to a *specific* question about storing beer?

Comment: @waxeagle I hoped to find a set of rules for storing beer that is applicable to pretty much any sort of beer (with exceptions, as usual).

Comment: if this site is going to succeed we're going to have to *stop* assuming that there *is* a general case for beer. If there was one we wouldn't need this site.

Comment: @waxeagle Good point. I will split this up in more precise and specialized questions.